# Блок закрывает всплывающее окно

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Подключал оплату на сайт человеку, он попросил заодно сделать форму всплывающую. Я в html, css не особо, поэтому набросал вариантик, но возникла проблема - часть формы закрывают другие блоки. Не могли бы вы помочь мне с решением этой проблемы? 
P.S. z-index у других блоков не выставлен, вот только в форме.
P.S.S. Если форму в другое место переместить нормально отображается. Возможно дело в заголовке или кнопке?

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Сам код формы:

```
                <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">X</a>
                        <p style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 14px;"><b>Заявка</b></p>
                        <div class = "input-field">
                        <p><b>Фото</b></p>
                        <p class = "gg">на Вашу страницу</p></div>

                        <div class = "input-field"><input type = "text" placeholder = "Имя"></div>
                        <div class = "input-field"><input type = "text" placeholder = "E-Mail"></div>
                        <div class = "input-field"><input type = "text" placeholder = "Ссылка на запись"></div>

                        <div style = "padding-top: 45px;"><p>К оплате:</p>
                        <b>199p</b></div>

                        <div class="service-order input-field">
                            <a class="button g" href="#">Оплатить →</a>
                            <div class = "clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .modalDialog {
            position: fixed;
            width: 410px;
            height: 470px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 22px 0;
            font-size: 18px;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: top;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 99999;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            display: none;
            pointer-events: none;
            float: center;
        }

        .modalDialog:target {
            display: block;
            pointer-events: auto;
        }

        .modalDialog > div {
            width: 400px;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 10px;
            }

        .close {
            background: #606061;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            line-height: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -12px;
            text-align: center;
            top: -10px;
            width: 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            }

        .clear{
        clear: both;
        }
```

Comment: А где Вы видите, что что-то закрывает? Или Вы о том кусочке зеленой полоски под формой? Так он просто выглядывает с под формы, но не перекрывает.

Comment: Можете выложить весь код на codepen например?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, вся форма выглядит вот так: http://i.imgur.com/L9YbzT9.jpg

Comment: @Abmin, вот: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNzMaz, всю страницу не стал выносить, ибо там картинки, а только конретно этот блок. Кликать(!) по кнопку "Заказать" второго блока и там внизу появляется эта модалка криво :( Общий CSS сайта в поле "CSS", мой вынесен в style в HTML.

Comment: Так у Вас там ничего не закрывает) Просто цвет текста в форме сливается с фоном. Попробуйте изменить цвет текста на черный.

http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/eBOqLZ?editors=1100

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, ой, действительно, спасибо Вам :)

Comment: @Felix =) не за что

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, возможно подскажите ещё как затемнение вокруг окна сделать? У меня только с окном выходит как ни крути.

Comment: @Felix, http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/eBOqLZ?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Вы немного намудрили с формой, у вас position: fixed перебивается position: relative, т.к последнее ниже. свойство float имеет только 2 значения: right  и left, если вы хотите, что бы форма всплывала по центру окна, вот простой пример: codepen.io/d-batmanov/pen/WEzEgY